# How can I retrive the model.pkl in the experiment in Databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks, datastore, mlflow

I want to retrieve the pickle off my trained model, which I know is in the run file inside my experiments in Databricks.

It seems that the `mlflow.pyfunc.load_model` can only do the `predict` method.

There is an option to directly access the pickle?

I also tried to use the path in the run using the `pickle.load(path)` (example of path: dbfs:/databricks/mlflow-tracking/20526156406/92f3ec23bf614c9d934dd0195/artifacts/model/model.pkl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found the solution which can be done by the following two approaches:

1. Use the customized predict function at the moment of saving the model (check [databricks](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#model-customization) documentation for more details).

example give by Databricks

```
class AddN(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return model_input.apply(lambda column: column + self.n)
# Construct and save the model
model_path = "add_n_model"
add5_model = AddN(n=5)
mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path=model_path, python_model=add5_model)

# Load the model in `python_function` format
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)
```

2. Load the model artefacts as we are downloading the artefact:

```
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

client = MlflowClient()

tmp_path = client.download_artifacts(run_id="0c7946c81fb64952bc8ccb3c7c66bca3", path='model/model.pkl')

f = open(tmp_path,'rb')

model = pickle.load(f)

f.close()

 

client.list_artifacts(run_id="0c7946c81fb64952bc8ccb3c7c66bca3", path="")

client.list_artifacts(run_id="0c7946c81fb64952bc8ccb3c7c66bca3", path="model")
```

Comment: For the second solution/approach, what version of pickle package have you used? I experiment with the following packages: mlflow==1.22.0, cloudpickle==1.6.0, pickle5==0.0.12 and when loading the model via pickle.load("my_onened_pkl_file"), I got the error:  in load_reduce stack[-1] = func(*args) TypeError: code() takes at most 15 arguments (16 given)

Comment: mlflow == 2.0.1; cloudpickle == 2.0.0; pickle  == 4.0.

Comment: Thank you, Leonardo! Can you please tell me which Python version?

Comment: The Python version is: 3.9.5

Answer (score 3):

Use the frmwk's native load_model() method (e.g. sklearn.load_model()) or download_artifacts()

Comment: but what I use for path? Or I give the run code?